# Creating array of hours in a day in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to create something like this in JavaScript

```
var date = {
    "29-Sept-2014" : ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"], //yesterday
    "30-Sept-2014" : ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"], //today
    "01-Oct-2014" : ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"] //tomorrow
};
```

Structure is, I want to have all the hours in a day in an array for three days. Yesterday, Current Date and Tomorrow..

***What I am trying to achieve -***

I want to create a table that has hours of 3 days( yesterday, today and tomorrow) as columns.

> Done something like this - serves the purpose. Thanks anyway guys :-)

**http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/n8egxo2d/3/**

Code snippet -

```js
var date = {}, newDate = new Date();
for (j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
    var tempDate = new Date(), tempHourArr = [];
    tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() - j);
    console.log(tempDate);
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        var hour = tempDate.setHours(i),
            minutes = tempDate.setMinutes(0),
            stringHour = (tempDate.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') +  
                         tempDate.getHours() + ":" + 
                         (tempDate.getMinutes() < 10 ?  '0' : '') + 
                         tempDate.getMinutes();
        tempHourArr.push(stringHour);
    }
    console.log(Date.create(tempDate).short());
    date[Date.create(tempDate).short()] = tempHourArr;
}

$("#codeHere").html(JSON.stringify(date, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sugar/1.4.1/sugar-full.min.js"></script>
<pre id="codeHere">

</pre>
```

I am not getting any idea on how to achieve this using JavaScript code.. any idea?

Comment: Could you explain why you are trying to do this? It could be that you are [addressing the wrong issue.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @George I will update it in thread above :-)

Comment: @George edited question with appropriate information and sample jsfiddle that I have tried.